# Use of undeclared identifier "TableCell" in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am using the code below and getting (Use of undeclared identifier "TableCell")
In the property attribute inspector TableCell is already defined under custom

Any idea?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    int row = [indexPath row];
    cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
    cell.Desctiptionlabel.text = _Description[row];
    cell.ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_Images[row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: method, you must remember to register the identifier with a class or a NIB first.

That code for your class will probably look something like the following in viewDidLoad, perhaps.

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:"TableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Alternatively, you can use the older dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method, but you will have to handle the case that cell will be nil after dequeue and you will need to load the cell from a nib or instantiate a new object manually.

As an aside, the convention in Objective-C development is to use lower camel case class member names and local variables.